# How to interpret it? in Mozilla Firefox JavaScript Engine

Tags: c++, spidermonkey

I've try to understand how spider-monkey engine work, but i can't understand what following code mean because of my bad cpp knowledge @_@

```
typedef Handle<JSObject*>                   HandleObject;
typedef Handle<js::Module*>                 HandleModule;
typedef Handle<js::ScriptSourceObject *>    HandleScriptSource;
typedef Handle<JSFunction*>                 HandleFunction; 
typedef Handle<JSScript*>                   HandleScript;
typedef Handle<JSString*>                   HandleString;
typedef Handle<jsid>                        HandleId;
typedef Handle<Value>                       HandleValue;
```

I think `<JSObject*>`, etc)... are template type, but '*' means pointer?

Comment: Yes? What exactly are you unclear about, you seem to understand it after all? A pointer type can be used as a template parameter as well

Comment: You might want to pick up a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465) to solidify your C++ foundations.